# derivative of riemann zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I try to find a represantation for the derivative of the riemann zeta function.
I do have for $\Re(s)>0$ and $s \neq 1$

$\zeta(s)=\dfrac{1}{s-1}+1-s\int_{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{s+1}} dx$

My question is this expression true:

$\zeta(s)' =- \dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2}-\int_{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{s+1}} dx+s(s+1)\int_{1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}
{x^{s+2}} dx$

feeling I have made a mistake, assuming it is true we obtain

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \zeta(1+it)'(it)+\zeta(1+it)= 1-\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{2}} dx$

Comment: yes, $\displaystyle \frac{d}{ds} x^{-s} = -(\ln x) x^{-s}$,  in the same way that $\zeta^{(k)}(s) = (-1)^k\sum_n (\ln n)^k n^{-s}$ and $\zeta'(s) = \frac{-1}{(s-1)^2} -\int_1^\infty (x-\lfloor x \rfloor) (1-s\ln x) x^{-s-1} dx$

Comment: Oh dear I have made a big mistake thanks! A little question why one can change integration and derivation?

Comment: because everything converges absolutely (write the limit explicity, and prove that the residual  tends to $0$). you can also use one of your favorite convergence theorem such as dominated or monotone convergence theorem